# Calculate the startLifetime of a ParticleSystem in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I want to handle the particle system by code. If a parent cube got a height of 10 units the particle system should calculate the startLifeTime (to reach the top of the cube) on its own.

So.. the calculation I use is

> startLifetime = cubeHeight / startSpeed

Now the code

```
private void Start()
{
    Vector3 liftScale = transform.localScale; // The scaling of my object

    ParticleSystem.ShapeModule particleShape = liftParticles.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().shape; // reference to the shape
    particleShape.radius = liftScale.x > liftScale.z ? liftScale.x : liftScale.z; // set the radius

    ParticleSystem.MainModule particleMain = liftParticles.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>().main; // reference to the PS.main
    particleMain.startLifetime = liftScale.y / particleMain.startSpeed; // set the startLifetime
}
```

When using this code the compiler says

> Operator cannot be applied to operands of type 'float' and
>   'ParticleSystem.MinMaxCurve'

So how can I calculate `liftScale.y / particleMain.startSpeed` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `particleMain.startSpeed.constant`.

Answer (score 0):

Thats means the particleMain.startSpeed has MinMaxCurve type.
Try to replace it by particleMain.startSpeedMultiplier.